Why does the `buyNode` function in my contract process in ETH instead of USDT, even though I'm explicitly passing USDT as the payment token parameter?
Question:
I'm working with a smart contract deployed at address 0xECf65aBAE21E2504E4af138b3d35a3ed0Ed42c7D to buy nodes using USDT as the payment token. Here’s what I’m doing:

I called the approve function on the USDT contract (0xFd086bC7CD5C481DCC9C85ebE478A1C0b69FCbb9) with an allowance of 3000000.
I then called the buyNode function with these parameters:

value: 2.8436223128354270
quantity: 1
referrerCode: ""
paymentToken: 0xFd086bC7CD5C481DCC9C85ebE478A1C0b69FCbb9 (address of the USDT token)



Despite setting paymentToken to USDT, the transaction appears to process as if it’s using ETH, as seen in the logs. Is there a possible issue in the buyNode function implementation that might cause it to ignore the paymentToken parameter and default to ETH?

Since, you're passing USDT token address in the paymentToken field, you don't need to pass the amount in the value field, you can just pass it as 0.

Because, if you pass any amount in value field, then it'll be considered as msg.value and will pop-up the wallet to spend the corresponding amount in native token (i.e., ETH) along with the gas fees while calling the function.
